# How to make a 2d printer easily using arduino?

Tags: arduino, programming

Can we use arduino programming and make a simple 2d printer? What kind of equipment are needed?

Comment: The Arduino programming may be fairly easy - the tough part will be putting the ink on the paper in the right spots.

Comment: If you are making printer from scratch you'd need quite a few precision parts, like guiding rails, at least 2 steppers with drivers for them and some kind of printing head with 1 solenoid minimum. It might be much easier to find old printer, gut it's electronics and use mechanics under Arduino control

Comment: Google arduino cdrom pen

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on CNC machines with arduinos out there

Comment: @Passerby that is soooo cool use of garbage! But I must point out it is actually a "plotter", not "printer". Principal difference would be in absolute positioning vs sequential raster.

Comment: Get an Arduino with 10 digital outputs, a couple inputs, and an MX-80 printer.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of tutorials on CNC machines with arduinos out there. The equipment needed? An arudino, a stepper motor driver, 2 stepper motors (at least and a frame with lead screws or belts (much cheaper) and rails (frames with stepper are readily available on your favorite site that sells Chinese stuff)